# Why aren't I displaying different PHP date values for my headers?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to display news headers with date of postage beside them. For some reason, the date for each one of them is the same; I didn't post all of them on the same day as the date in the database is different for each.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'olearyinternational');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` order by created desc limit 8';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
$date = date('jS F Y', $d);
// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
    // Make sure there are some files in there
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
    }
    else {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
            <li class="good-font"><a href="news.php"><?php echo $row['title'] ?><span id = "post_date"><?php echo $date; ?></a></li>
<?php
        }
        // Close table
        echo '</table>';
        // Free the result
        $result->free();
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
    echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
}
// Close the mysql connection
$dbLink->close();
?>
```

Comment: when do you set the variable $d ?

Comment: $d = strtotime($row['created']);
       $id = $row['id'];
                            $date = date('jS F Y', $d);

Comment: $date = date('jS F Y', $d);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $date is initialized once, up where you do your query. You'll need to echo the postdate in each row instead of $date. Check your schema, it'll probably be something like $row['date'] or $row['post_date']. If you need to change the formatting, do it within the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, I just put this $d = strtotime($row['created']);
          $id = $row['id'];
                               $date = date('jS F Y', $d); into while loop and it worked.